# Energy minimization with a parameter inside an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization

**Context:**

Real 3D space quantum mechanics

**Introduction:**

Let us define the function square integrable $R(u)$, $0 \leq u \leq + \infty$, with $Z$ a positive integer:

$$ R(r) = 2 (Z-Z_c)^{3/2} e^{-(Z-Z_c)u} $$

with the normalization property (spherical coordinates):

$$ \int_0^{+ \infty} u^2 R(u)^2 d u = 1 $$

And the variable $Z_c$ that is also a function of $R(u)$:

$$ Z_c = \int_0^{u_c} u^2 R(u)^2 d u $$

**Minimization:**

The variable $u_c$ is our unknown. We want to minimize the function (energy) $\epsilon(u_c)$ defined by:

$$ \epsilon = - (Z-Z_c)^2 + \alpha \int_{u_c}^{+ \infty} u R(u)^2 d u $$

with $\alpha$ a positive integer. Then I want to minimize this function with respect to $u_c$ so I have:

$$ \partial_{u_c} \epsilon = 0$$

that gives ($R(0) > 0$, $R(+ \infty) = 0$)):

$$ 2 u_c (Z-Z_c) - \alpha = 0 $$

I don't even know if it is possible to solve this equation since when I replace $Z_c$ by its value I have:

$$ 2 u_c \left( Z -  \int_0^{u_c} u^2 R(u)^2 d u \right) - \alpha = 0 $$

And it is difficult because it is like a "telescopic function"... Do you have an idea to minimize $\epsilon$ with a numerical approximation or something else ?
Thank you for reading.